# Can Ansible be used for deployment to an IBM mainframe z/OS OMVS

Tags: ansible, zos

From what I understand, Ansible is agentless and can connect using OpenSSH.  I believe that Ansible requires Python.  We currently do not have Python available (Jython is available) on this mainframe, and I'm not sure that a reliable port exists, although I have found some possibilities (e.g. http://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source/python?ver=2.7.6).

Is Python, or anything else, required on the target server/mainframe to use Ansible to deploy files?

Answer (score 0):

According to
[the install docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements),
the target machine should only need a functioning sshd and a pretty
old Python version.

You may be somewhat limited on the
[modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/modules_by_category.html)
you can use with ZOS, but some will work, and you could probably write
more yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Red Hat Ansible Certified Content for IBM Z](https://ibm.github.io/z_ansible_collections_doc/index.html)
. There is Ansible collections for [z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/products/zos), [CICS](https://www.ibm.com/products/cics-transaction-server), [IMS](https://www.ibm.com/products/ims), [z/OSMF](https://www.ibm.com/products/zos/management-facility), [HMC](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247748.pdf).

According to the [documentation](https://ibm.github.io/z_ansible_collections_doc/ibm_zos_core/docs/source/community_guides_docs/zos_ansible_module_testing.html), the prerequisites are:

> Control node
>
> - Ansible version: 2.9 or later
> - Python: 3 or later
> - OpenSSH
>
> Managed node
> IBM Open Enterprise Python for z/OS
>
> - z/OS V2R3 or later
> - IBM Z Open Automation Utilities (ZOAU)
> - The z/OS® shell
> - z/OS OpenSSH